# Filter existing entries from a EF result-set

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a table with existing customers and their customer ids. When I add a new customer to the table, I use autocomplete but I would like to exclude the existing customers from the result set.

That's what I have so far:

```
public JsonResult AutoCompleteCustomerNumberLimit([FromBody] object value)
        {
            var input = new
            {
                value = ""
            };

            var existingEntries = luxWebSamContext.Limits.Select(u => u.PkKdnr).ToList();
            var company = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(value.ToString(), input);

            var isNumeric = int.TryParse(company.value, out _);

            var result = (from c in AlContext.AutolineAccts
                          where EF.Functions.Like(
                               isNumeric ? c.AccountCode : c.CustomerSname, "%" + company.value + "%")
                                && !existingEntries.Contains(c.AccountCode)
                          select new
                          {
                              CompanyName = c.CustomerSname.Trim(),
                              CompanyNumber = c.AccountCode.Trim(),
                              CompanyStreet = c.AddressLine1.Trim(),
                              CompanyZip = c.Postcode.Trim(),
                              CompanyCity = c.AddressLine4.Trim(),
                              CompanyCountry = c.Eccode.Trim()

                          }).Distinct()
                            .Take(10);

            return Json(result);
        }
```

Pretty easy to follow. `existingEntries` holds a list of the IDs of my existing customers that I want to exclude from the result set. `company` holds the partial ID or name from my autocomplete input field.

The problem is: this kind of code is working within another function of my app with a small number of existing entities. But here I get a timeout after 30 sec. of waiting for the query to end. I have 11.000 rows in the existingEntries list, which might be too much for that kind of query.

Any ideas here?

I tried to split the work load in two steps:

First I retrieve the results including the existing customers:

```
var result = (from c in AlContext.AutolineAccts
                              where EF.Functions.Like(
                                   isNumeric ? c.AccountCode : c.CustomerSname, "%" + company.value + "%")
                                    
                              select new
                              {
                                  CompanyName = c.CustomerSname.Trim(),
                                  CompanyNumber = c.AccountCode.Trim(),
                                  CompanyStreet = c.AddressLine1.Trim(),
                                  CompanyZip = c.Postcode.Trim(),
                                  CompanyCity = c.AddressLine4.Trim(),
                                  CompanyCountry = c.Eccode.Trim()
    
                              }).Distinct()
                                .Take(10);
```

And then I remove the existing customers from the results... Something like that but I don't get the syntax right:

```
   result = result.Where(x => x.CompanyNumber != existingEntries.);
```

Comment: maybe by mistake you have ```.``` in the last code part on the end

Comment: No that was just to highlight that i don't know how to continue from there. It's just pseudo-code.